# Using nls and ggplot2 to fit a logarithmic curve to data

Tags: r, modeling, ggplot2, nls

I am using R to fit data on a logarithmic curve with equation:

y = a * log(b * x)

My data looks like this:

```
#Creating example data
pre <- c(946116, 1243227, 1259646, 1434124, 1575268, 2192526, 3252832, 6076519)  
post <- c(907355, 1553586, 1684253, 2592938, 1919173, 1702644,3173743, 3654198)  
data <- data.frame(pre,post)

#Plotting data
  ggplot(data, aes(x=pre, y=post))+
  geom_point()
```

[image: Example plot]

But when I try to fit a logarithmic curve using geom_smooth, I get an error.

```
# Fitting logarithmic curve
ggplot(data, aes(x=pre, y=post))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method="nls", se=FALSE,
              method.args=list(formula=y~a*log(b*x),
                               start=c(a=100, b=2)))
```

Warning messages:

```
1: In log(b * x) : NaNs produced
2: Computation failed in `stat_smooth()`:
Missing value or an infinity produced when evaluating the model
```

I get similar issues when I try to create a logarithmic model in nls, without using ggplot

```
model <- nls(data=data, 
             formula=y~a*log(b*x),
             start=list(a=100, b=2))
```

Warning messages:

```
Error in numericDeriv(form[[3L]], names(ind), env) : 
  Missing value or an infinity produced when evaluating the model
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
3: In log(b * x) : NaNs produced
```

As someone who is new to R, I  don't quite understand what the error messages are trying to tell me. I know that I need to change how I am specifying start conditions, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=pre, y=post))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method="nls", se=FALSE, formula=y~a*log(x)+k,
              method.args=list(start=c(a=1, k=1)))
```

[image]

Notice that it's essentially the same formula, but now `k = a * log(b)`:

`a * log(b * x) = a * {log(b) + log(x)} = a * log(x) + a * log(b) = a * log(x) + k`

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of problems in your *nls* call. 1) You're using the variables *x* and *y*, when these variables don't exist.  They should be *pre* and *post*.  2) The size of numbers is giving *nls* trouble.  It helps if you divide them by 1,000,000.

```
pre <- c(946116, 1243227, 1259646, 1434124, 1575268, 2192526, 3252832, 6076519)  
post <- c(907355, 1553586, 1684253, 2592938, 1919173, 1702644,3173743, 3654198)

pre = pre/1000000
post = post/1000000

data <- data.frame(pre,post)

model <- nls(data=data, 
             formula=post~a*log(b*pre),
             start=list(a=1, b=1))

summary(model)
```

But as shown in the previous answer, changing the form of the equation will help without needing to change the scale of the data.

```
pre <- c(946116, 1243227, 1259646, 1434124, 1575268, 2192526, 3252832, 6076519)  
post <- c(907355, 1553586, 1684253, 2592938, 1919173, 1702644,3173743, 3654198)

data <- data.frame(pre,post)

model <- nls(data=data, 
             formula=post~a*log(pre)+b,
             start=list(a=1, b=0))

summary(model)
```